# Simplifying in Prolog

Tags: prolog

This is a simple mini program I have here that simplifies addition expressions that are queried. I can't seem to figure out how to finish it off. When I query the following:

```
sim(sum(sum(x,1),5),Val,[x:X]).
```

My result is `Val = X+1+5`. I would like it to simplify all the way to `X+6`.

Here is the code:

```
sim(Var, Value, Lst) :- member(Var:Value, Lst).
sim(Num, Num, _) :- number(Num).
sim(sum(Left, Right), Value, Lst) :-
     sim(Left, LeftVal, Lst),
     sim(Right, RightVal, Lst),
     so(Value,LeftVal,RightVal).

so(Result, X, Y) :-
   number(X),
   number(Y), !,
   Result is X + Y.

so(Result, X, Y) :-         // debugging        so(Result,_,Y) :-
   Result = X + Y.          // Y value             write(Y), Result = Y.
```

What I do know is that my program is trying to simplify `X+1` before adding `X+1` and 5. When I change the last line of my "so" method to only give `Y` to Result I get `Val = 6`. Before that line I write `Y` to the screen for debugging purposes and it gives me `1 5` because of the recursion. Which means `X` must be a var? Is there a corner case not here that will allow me to simplify addition all the way down?

What I am noticing is that "so" never adds 1 and 5 because they are never arguments together in the "so" method that checks for X and Y to be numbers. X and 1 are the first arguments, then upon recursion `X+1` and 5 are the arguments and it doesn't execute because `number(X)` fails when X is `X+1`

Comment: I think you might need a more sofisticated mechanism, making use of expressions in canonical "normal" form. You could take a look at how the CLP libraries implement simplification for inspiration.

If I recall correctly SWI-prolog's CLP(R) package does basically what you do, but 'sim' generates expressions in normal form and 'so' would merge two such expressions into another expression in normal form.

Comment: @vmg Yeah I just took a look at the CLP library, so what you are saying is in this case if "so" has arguments X, being X+1 and Y, being 5 I should put them in an expression together?

Comment: No, I mean you might have to define an 'internal representation' of expressions that deals with 'variables' and numbers, so you can separate the ones from the others. If you only want to deal with addition the representation should be straightforward: simply use two lists. If you mix and match more than one operator it might require a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500560/swi-prolog-simplifying-expressions) is an example of an expression simplifier that separates 'symbols' from 'values' using two lists.

Notice how it uses the fact, in parsing and unparsing, that the only operator joining symbols and values is +.

Comment: I see, I will attempt to make use of what is going on in that solution to hopefully get my solution and see what I come up with.