# Symbolic & Numeric Calculation

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm a Computer Science student, on last semester we learned to program in Prolog. Now I'm trying to have fun with it.
I'm trying to build a program that given a symbolic/mathematical input it return the result.
example:

```
? solve(2+3+Z+K+5+Z+1, R).
R = 11+2*Z+K or R = 11+Z+K+Z
```

This is the snippet (for + operation)

```
solve(X, R) :-
    eval(X, R).

eval(X, X) :- var(X),!.
eval(X, X) :- number(X), !.  
eval(+(X, Y), R) :-
    eval(X, A),
    eval(Y, B),
    add(A, B, R), !.

add(A, B, R) :-
    number(A),
    number(B),
    !,
    R is A + B.
add(A, B, A+B) :-
    var(A); var(B),!.
add(A+X, B, R+X) :-
    number(A),
    number(B),
    var(X),
    !,
    R is A + B.
add(X+A, B, R+X) :-
    number(A),
    number(B),
    var(X),
    !,
    R is A + B.
```

I have some issue when numbers are separated by many variables, example:

```
? solve(5+Z+5+4+K+Z+6, R).
FALSE.
```

or, (not form source code above), if numbers are separated by many variables, they are not "processed", example:

```
? solve(5+Z+K+7, R).
R = 5+Z+K+7.
```

Thanks for help, any suggestion or reference will be appreciate.

Comment: You might want to look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500560/swi-prolog-simplifying-expressions) for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit more involved than what your code is doing at the moment. At the end, you seem to want to have a solver for symbolic equations, is that so? So for example, if you type into [Wolfram Alfa](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2B3%2BZ%2BK%2B5%2BZ%2B1%20%3D%20R) your equation, `2+3+Z+K+5+Z+1 = R`, you get the answer `K+2 Z+11 = R`.

Similar functionality is provided for example by metafont:

```
$ mf
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)
**\relax

*tracingequations:=tracingonline:=1;

*2+3+a+b+5+a+1=r;
## a=0.5r-0.5b-5.5

*x^2+3=0;
## x^2=-3
```

... and I guess by every program as Matlab, Mathematica, etc.

In Prolog, for integers, you get something very similar for free if you use [`library(clpfd)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd):

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).
true.

?- 2 + 3 + Z + K + Z + 1 #= R.
2*Z+K+ -1*R#= -6.
```

If you want to program this yourself, you should probably start with deciding how you want to represent your answers: as you see, the three programs demonstrated here choose different approaches. From there, you can either try to see how to get there yourself (see the comment by @lurker), or try to figure out how others have implemented it.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, 
I think i will try to understand how the library clpfd is implemented, and using the source given by @lurker implement my solution.
I will try to rapresent my result as a solution given by a student in his homework.
Thanks again.